# Navbar using Bootstrap 4 only shows hamburger menu and not the links

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have installed bootstrap 4.0.0beta2 and trying to use bootstrap's navbar menu. I pasted this content straight from bootstrap's navbar menu code just to practice. Here is my index.html. The navbar is suppused to show "home" "link" etc on a normal page and only supposed to collapse to a hamburger menu on a smaller screen but it is showing a hamburger menu on a big screen too. I am pretty sure I installed bootstrap correctly because other bootstrap features like modal works just fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Risque" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>Wordpress Learning</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascriptfiles/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascriptfiles/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascriptfiles/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="javascriptfiles/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you be more specific about the issue? And about the whole hamburger menu thing? First off, by the way, to ensure you've loaded all files properly check if the browser's console is giving you errors

Comment: With your code posted as it is with many local resources being referenced, it is hard to know what you are actually loading. you could set up a snippet with all of the code referenced from the appropriate CDNs and demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Do this: Remove duplicate jQuery files. Remove `bootstrap.js`, as you are using the bundle js. Change `navbar-toggleable-md` to `navbar-expand-md`.

Comment: I was just going to comment about the `navbar-toggleable-md` - good find @Klooven

Comment: @Klooven that fixed it thanks.